# Initializing AWS for rails app via cli error

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, devops

I am trying to deploy my rails app to AWS Beanstalk using the AWS CLI and it looks like when I am trying to initialize my repo I get an error because I don't have python installed? My question is, do I need python installed for this to work? Why would I need python if my app was developed in Ruby, or is this related to how Amazon built the tool?

```
$eb init
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 5, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3131, in <module>
        @_call_aside
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3117, in _call_aside
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS website states the requirements:

> The EB CLI is developed in Python and requires Python version 2.7 or 3.4 in order to run.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html

The CLI has nothing to do with Ruby or Rails, it's just that Amazon chose to code their tool in Python so you will need python to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I would like to point out that this answer is referring to the generalized AWS CLI while Jbur43 seems to be using the [elasticbeanstalk specific cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) which also happens to be written in Python.

Comment: Updated it to be more accurate.